# Identify snippets in different (real) languages in a text and apply certain rule

Tags: regex, scripting, linguistics

Could there be a way for me to identify which segments within a text are in a different language in order to format them distinctly?

For example, say I create a text file,

```
the dog chases the cat = der Hund jagt die Katze
"the dog is chasing the cat" in German would be "der Hund jagt die Katze"
```

Now the supposed script would have to parse this file, identify the snippets in German and transform it (for example) into

```
the dog chases the cat = **der Hund jagt die Katze**
"the dog is chasing the cat" in German would be "**der Hund jagt die Katze**"
```

Comment: Regular expressions probably aren't the right tool for this.  Instead, you need to use a parser.  For starters, the meaning of English words can be dependent on the context/grammar.  A regex can't really think that way.

Comment: I understand. I thought regular expressions might play a role here, but not that they would solve the main problem.

Comment: Yes, they might play a role, but I think you would need at least some parsing logic as well.